# Autocomplete people picker in sharepoint2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker

I have a problem in which I have to add an Auto Complete functionality for a new people picker of Sharepoint list `newform.aspx`

While Googling I found this

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/autocomplete-for-sharepoint-people-picker.aspx

Which is helpful but there are 2 main problems :

1. **it will pick data from a custom list**
   I want it to pick data from user profiles (directly from Sharepoint user profiles)
2. **it doesn't work with out of the box people picker**
   it works with a custom textbox though

Please help me out resolving these.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If it is Sharepoint 2010 you can do this by using the Javascript version of the Sharepoint Client Object Model to do the lookups.

If it is an older Sharepoint, it should still be possible to do this using the Web Services API.

You can add a lot of functionality to an SP page by using Javascript and JQuery and perhaps the Client Object Model.

Check these questions for more on Javascript/JQuery with Sharepoint:

- [Deploy jQuery using a SharePoint Feature or physical files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488194/deploy-jquery-using-a-sharepoint-feature-or-physical-files)
- [How to use jquery correctly in SharePoint Web Part - jquery doesn't always fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960143/how-to-use-jquery-correctly-in-sharepoint-web-part-jquery-doesnt-always-fire)