# Having error when using jquery.corner.js with jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to use jQuery Corner to get a curvy quicklaunch in my SharePoint 2010, but I am getting the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any ideas if this version are compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you reference JQuery is not working fine. How did you reference the jQuery? Refer this for example - [How to use jquery correctly in SharePoint Web Part - jquery doesn't always fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960143/how-to-use-jquery-correctly-in-sharepoint-web-part-jquery-doesnt-always-fire)

Regards,
Nitin Rastogi